# External powers of subsheaves of a coherent sheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

$\newcommand\F{\mathcal{F}}\newcommand\G{\mathcal{G}}$Suppose $\F$ is a subsheaf with generic rank $0$ of a coherent sheaf $\G$ with generic rank $p$ on a smooth variety $X$.  Is there a nonzero map from $\det(\F) \to \bigwedge^n \G$ for some $n$?

Comment: I am confused. Doesn't $\newcommand{\F}{\mathscr{F}}\newcommand{\rk}{\mathrm{rk}}\rk(\F)=0$ mean $\F=0$ and in particular, $\det(\F)=\F=0$? 

Comment: What do you mean by exterior powers of $\mathcal G$?

Comment: Dear john, I think it would help if you titled the question a little more specifically.

Comment: John: I think you should look at the article
`The projectivity of the moduli space of stable curves. I. Preliminaries on "det'' and "Div''.` of Knudsen and Mumford.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assuming that $det(\mathcal F)$ refers to some nonzero $\wedge^k\mathcal  F$, presumably the last nonzero one, and an exterior power of $\mathcal G$ is $\wedge^k \mathcal G$.

The map $\mathcal F \to \mathcal G$ naturally induces a map $\wedge^k \mathcal F \to \wedge^k \mathcal G$. This map is always injective, since we can just check this on the fiber, which is a vector space, and that's true for vector spaces. Since $det(\mathcal F)=\wedge^k(\mathcal  F)$ is nonzero, and the map to $\wedge^k \mathcal G$ is injective, it must be nonzero.

Comment: "This map is always injective, since we can just check this on the fiber ..."  What precisely do you mean by this?  For an injective homomorphism of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules, the base change to the residue field of a point need not be injective.  If the homomorphism is locally split, then I agree with your argument.  In fact, I feel that the question of the OP is ill-posed, since he does not tell us what definition of "det" he is using (my guess is the one used by Mumford).  